# [Heroku][Rails] ! Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

First of everything, this is my first question.
I used Strack Overflow just for years, an I want to say thank you for every single guy that expend time Asking and Answering questions.
You guys made possible my career

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app in Heroku but I'm receiving this error after pushing the branch:
**Failed to install gems via Bundler.**
My gems files are really simples:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.3.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'responders'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~>0.9.4'
gem 'httparty'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
#gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    active_model_serializers (0.9.7)
      activemodel (>= 3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    activejob (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
    activerecord (5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (9.0.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.1)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    dotenv (2.5.0)
    dotenv-rails (2.5.0)
      dotenv (= 2.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    httparty (0.16.2)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (1.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.2)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.4)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.4)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.0)
      actioncable (= 5.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sass (3.5.7)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.17)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.6.2)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.4)
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  dotenv-rails
  httparty
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (~> 0.21)
  rails (~> 5.2.0)
  responders
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.1p112

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.3
```

**Complete build log**

```
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.

            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js

            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order

-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.1

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing

       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the

       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.



       The dependencies in your gemfile changed



       You have added to the Gemfile:

       * responders

       * dotenv-rails

       * active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.4)

       * httparty



       You have deleted from the Gemfile:

       * capybara (< 4.0, >= 2.15)

       * chromedriver-helper

       * coffee-rails (~> 4.2)

       * selenium-webdriver

       * spring

       * spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)

       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing

       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the

       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.



       The dependencies in your gemfile changed



       You have added to the Gemfile:

       * responders

       * dotenv-rails

       * active_model_serializers (~> 0.9.4)

       * httparty



       You have deleted from the Gemfile:

       * capybara (< 4.0, >= 2.15)

       * chromedriver-helper

       * coffee-rails (~> 4.2)

       * selenium-webdriver

       * spring

       * spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)

 !

 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.

 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

 !     Push failed
```

I already tried re-building my Gemfile.lock.
I deleted it and run **bundle update** + **bundle install**

This is my first time in Heroku, and I afraid that maybe I'm pushing some incompatibles gems.

***About the settings:***
**ruby** 2.3.1 and **rails** 5.2.0

I will appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Comment: There is always additional information which gem did not install in the error message or at least some indication on what went wrong. Can you attach the full stacktrace? Also, which version of rails and ruby are you using?

Comment: Thanks @jedi, the versions are the ones in the gemfile, I will add it on the body of the question: ruby 2.3.1 and rails 5.2.0

Comment: Well, Heroku says "It looks like you removed some gems from Gemfile and did not run bundle install prior deploying to Heroku". Did you run bundle  install after removing the gems?

Comment: Try running this: `bundle; git add -f Gemfile.lock; git commit -am "add gemfile.lock"; git push heroku master`;

Comment: Yes @jedi, Many, many times! and I added the changes with git add ., committed an pushed it.

Comment: @JoshBrody I manually deleted the Gemfile.lock file. After that I run bundle install from the docker container that is running the server and have all the dependencies. That made the  Gemfile.lock appears again. I added it, committed and pushed, with the same result :( .

Comment: Are you working from another branch? If so you have to `git push heroku <branchname>:master`

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the current ruby version you are running into the gem file then running

bundle update --ruby

does the job pretty well.

This article from heroku explains more
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions